# How do I get using php?

Tags: php

I know that this is a simple question for PHP guys but I don't know the language and just need to do a simple "get" from another web page when my page is hit. i.e. signal the other page that this page has been hit.

EDIT: curl is not available to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If curl wrappers are on (they are per default), you can use:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.org');
```

Note that this happens synchronous, so before the request has completed, your page won't either. It would be better to log access to a logfile (or database) and export the data occasionally. Alternatively, you could do the request after your page has completed, and output has been sent to the client.

Comment: I think troelskn means file wrappers and not cURL wrappers, since you do not, necesserly, need cURL to use file_get_contents() with an HTTP protocol.

Comment: @gustavo You're right. I always thought those filewrappers used curl underneath, but it must have been something I made up, 'cause I can't find it in the manual to support it.

Answer (score 3):

Beware `file_get_contents()` and `fopen()`:

> If PHP has decided that filename specifies a registered protocol, and that protocol is registered as a network URL, PHP will check to make sure that allow_url_fopen is enabled. If it is switched off, PHP will emit a warning and the fopen call will fail.

Answer (score 2):

There's numerous ways... the simplest is `file_get_contents('http://...');`
Other functions like `fopen()` also support http: streams.

If you need more control, I'd suggest looking at curl (see `curl_init`)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to send a GET request with PHP. As mentioned above, you can use `file_get_contents`, `fopen` or cURL.

You can also use the [HTTP extension](http://php.net/http), the `fsockopen()` function or [streams](http://php.net/stream_get_contents) via `fopen`.

I'd advise checking out [what WordPress has done](http://trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/http.php), as it handles almost all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

Comment: It's not fair to vote this down for suggesting something that the question didn't rule out before the answer was posted. :(